# How to programatically detect a 64 bit or 32 bit machine?

Tags: 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I don't understand what 32 bit and 64 bit means. It seems that people say 64 bit computers run faster - but why? Does it mean that there are 64 bit integers instead of 32? If it's something like that, is there a way to write a program to determine if we're on a 32 bit or 64 bit machine?

Comment: There are ways - what computer language/OS are you using?

Comment: Any language is OK. I'd like it be as universal as possible though, so, for instance, Java, since pretty much every OS supports a jvm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On 64-bit machines pointers are 8 bytes (64 bits). On 32-bit machines they are 4 bytes (32 bits). Thus we can determine by the size of a pointer what we are dealing with, in it's simplest form:

```
#define IS_64BIT (sizeof(void *) == 8)
```

The only drawback is that a 64 bit computer running in 32 bit mode will register as 32 bit. Of course, this isn't actually important as for all intents and purposes a 32 bit OS on a 64 bit computer will be a 32 bit computer.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually several different things your asking here.

First of all there's the CPU.  Most modern day CPUs (within the past 5-years approx) will support 64-bit.

Now just because the CPU supports it doesn't mean the OS supports it, that's where you have either 64-bit OS or 32-bit OS (32-bit is also known as x86, there's small technical differences in the x86 refers to the CPU instruction set, but for most common usage x86 and 32-bit are interchangeable)

Even if the OS supports it, it doesn't mean the specific program you're running supports 64-bit.  What most (if not all?) 64-bit OS's do is they have a 32-bit emulation mode so you can still run 32-bit programs.

Now for your question of how to determine which architecture you're running on, the most reliable way is to ask the OS through some API call.

As for why 64-bit is sometimes considered faster, it because with 32-bits it is only possible to address 4GB of memory, whereas with 64-bit the limit imposed by address space is much higher (as in about 4 billion times higher) and the limiting factor is hardware not address space.  As to when and why more memory is faster, that's a separate topic altogether.

Answer (score 3):

**64-bit** machines do not run faster than 32-bit machines except in cases where 64-bit math is being done or in cases where more than 4 GB of RAM is needed.

**64-bit AMD** (and later Intel) machines run faster than 32-bit x86 machines because when AMD designed the new instruction set they added more CPU registers and made SSE math the default.

32-bit x86 systems can waste a lot of CPU time pushing data around in RAM, while a x86_64 system can store that data in CPU registers instead. Registers are much faster than level-1 CPU cache. Having more registers also saves CPU instructions that otherwise need to store the old value of a register in RAM, load in a different value from RAM, then load the original value back from RAM.

In some especially register-starved cases the extra registers can gain 30% speed for a program. The benefit is usually much less than that.

The speed benefits from assuming SSE2 are many. In 32-bit CPUs SSE instructions may or may not exist, so to use them the software needs to have clumsy test code and two (or more!) implementation of the math functions. Most software just doesn't care enough and so it never bothers, always falling back on x87 FPU math from the 486 days. The 64-bit CPUs made SSE2 a required part of the instruction set, so all x86_64 programs are free to assume it exists and use it in all cases.

Answer (score -1):

64bit computers do not run faster, per se. It just can support higher precision (larger integers, more precise floats).

In some rare cases, libraries might jam two 32bit numbers into 64bits to perform a large number of parallel operations, possibly resulting in potentially up to 2x speedup. This might occur for some highly optimized scientific/numeric libraries, or in special applications that (for some reason or another) have been highly optimized at a very low level. For example, some multimedia software. It should be noted that such applications could always have made this tradeoff even in 32bit mode, but chose not to; they are merely trading away precision (which they may not need) for parallelism.

Operating system benchmarks which reveal faster performance (maybe <10% improvement) are not necessarily related to 64bit-related optimizations. 64bit architectures may be correlated with having for example more registers or advanced features that programs can take aware of [citation: http://www.tuxradar.com/content/ubuntu-904-32-bit-vs-64-bit-benchmarks ], which may be the cause of a performance difference (as well as other variables).

How to determine whether a CPU is 32bit or 64bit depends on what OS you are using. For example on Linux, you can call `uname -a`, though there's probably a better way to do so. If you're using C/C++, see the other answer for a way to determine it in a program.

Comment: And let's not forget more physical memory due to the larger address space.

Comment: 64 bit OSs run faster than 32bit... http://64-bit-computers.com/windows-vista-32-bit-vs-64-bit-benchmark.html

Comment: @Oskar it can but necessarily.  It depends on what kinds of operations you're running.  In some cases it can be slower and shown in the like you posted.

Comment: @Stu: I'm aware and thought of mentioning, but did not related to topic of question, thank you though. @Oskar: Maybe faster by at most 10%, probably experimental error, or more likely small accidental tweaks to the operating system. If you run the same program on 32bit or 64bit, it will run the same speed unless you are doing major hacks like stuffing 32bits into 64bits two-by-two.

Comment: @ninjagecko Yes, probably a program would run at the same speed. But lots of OS's run faster

Comment: Some programs will run *much* faster on a 64-bit architecture if they're written correctly as they can do more work in a single instruction. Generally though this only applies to computationally intensive tasks that have been optimised for 64-bit. Signal processing would be a good example of a domain where this is true.

Comment: @Stu: I'm aware, I already mentioned in my comment at Oskar. That may be worth adding though to the answer, thank you.