# Programmatically detect CPU architecture at runtime

Tags: c++, c, assembly, cpu-architecture

Is it possible to check the CPU architecture(is 64 or 32 bits) in a x86/x86-64 CPU without gathering information from the OS or some API, by means of low level code (C/C++ or assembly)?

One could check for the size of a pointer, like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928218/how-to-programatically-detect-a-64-bit-or-32-bit-machine), but, from what I understand, this way lets you know the OS architecture is compiled for, because a 64 bit CPU running a 32 bit OS would report wrong results.

Maybe some `cpuid` instruction or similar could do the trick but I couldn't find anything that fully satisfies these requirements. If you think it's not possible, I would appreciate a good reason to justify this (this may be a less objective answer). If you are wondering, this is for a CPU detection software.

Edit:
In [Determine 32/64 bit architecture in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569021/determine-32-64-bit-architecture-in-assembly), OP does not get some specific answer that explain how to do it, just that you should use cpuid, and links to [How do you detect the CPU architecture type during run-time with GCC and inline asm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917761/how-do-you-detect-the-cpu-architecture-type-during-run-time-with-gcc-and-inline), that shows a good answer to me, but it isn't as complete as the answer that I marked as accepted, because Remy Lebeau gives a detailed explanation and tells which specific cpuid bit must be queried, instead of just writing some code, and I find it more appropiate for my question, because it is explained at a higher level scope(I never mentioned gcc, the second post does)

Comment: If you compile your executable for 64bit, the CPU must be 64bit. But if you compile your executable for 32bit, the CPU may be 32bit or 64bit (if a 32bit emulator is installed, like WOW64 on Windows), so you MUST query the hardware details to differentiate. Best to get that from the OS, but the `CPUID` instruction does have a ["Processor Info and Feature Bits"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX=1:_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) query (look at the `ia64` feature flag in particular on Intel CPUs).

Comment: Are you asking about x86 / x86-64 in particular, or 32/64-bit processors in general? (I'm not sure there is a general answer.)

Comment: Isn't this the tail wagging the dog? The code is compiled for a particular architecture.

Comment: Or the `long mode` bit from the ["Extended Processor Info and Feature Bits"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX=80000001h:_Extended_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) query on AMD CPUs.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau You assume that we deal with x86 here only, don't you? What about others like ARM?

Comment: I doubt there exists a general approach. The C  standard does not provide for a mechanism at least. Assembly can only be used if you already assume a certain target architecture...

Comment: You also do not define what OS you assume. Under Linux, the changes are high that you find the appropriate information in the `/proc` (look at the content of `/proc/cpuinfo`)  or the  `/sys` file system.

Comment: For the **general** case, this is impossible; I've tried at length. The best you can do is write a bunch of hard-coded Triple->{various pieces of information} tables, but even this won't save you from GCC's ./configure flags or `-m` options. If you have constraints, list them.

Comment: @MichaelBeer ARM doesn't have a `CPUID` instruction like Intel/AMD do, but it does have a [`CPUID` register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0395b/CIHCAGHH.html) instead.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: This sounds like it would make sense to forge an answer out of your comments, wouldn't it ;)

Comment: There is nothing in the `C++` standard for it and not every `CPU` is bound to report itself with exactly the same code so I think you are stuck with querying the operating system.

Comment: @MichaelBeer done

Comment: RemyLebeau zx485 Looks good but I need time to check it out. Specially, really liked your approach, RemyLebeau. MichaelBeer I don't define a OS because I was looking for a non OS dependent solution. prl I'm sorry, I have edited the post to clarify that. Thank you all for your comments, need time to test some of your ideas.

Comment: What do you want to do with this information?  Do you want to create a 32-bit executable that checks whether a 64-bit executable could run on the current OS?  Or are you writing a kernel that checks if it can switch to 64-bit mode after booting as far as 32-bit mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you compile your executable for 64bit, the CPU must be 64bit only.

If you compile your executable for 32bit, the CPU *may* be 32bit or 64bit (if a 64bit CPU is capable of running 32bit code), so you MUST query the CPU to differentiate.  Best to get that from the OS when possible, but the CPU *may* have its own query for that info.

For instance, on an x86 or x86-64 CPU, there is a [`CPUID`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) instruction available:

- [On Intel CPUs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/techspec/24161821.pdf), `CPUID`'s ["Processor Info and Feature Bits"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX=1:_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) query includes an `ia64` feature flag (IA64 processor emulating x86).
- [On AMD CPUs](https://support.amd.com/TechDocs/25481.pdf), `CPUID`'s ["Extended Processor Info and Feature Bits"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX=80000001h:_Extended_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) query includes a [`long mode`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode) feature flag.

`CPUID` has a ["Get vendor ID"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX=0:_Get_vendor_ID_(including_EAX=1:_Get_CPUID)) query to determine the CPU manufacturer.

Comment: But if your x86-64 CPU is running a 32-bit OS, it still won't be able to run a 64-bit executable.  So it's pretty much not useful to detect this CPU capability which the OS won't let you take advantage of.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to write code for x86 that runs in either 32- or 64-bit mode. If you are running such code, you can check which mode you are in with the following:

```
get_mode:
        mov eax, 1
        dec eax
        test eax, eax
        ret
```

In 64-bit mode, `dec eax` becomes the REX.W prefix for the test instruction. Thus, this code returns 0 when run in 32-bit mode and returns 1 when run in 64-bit mode. It also sets Z accordingly, so it can be used from another assembly language function like this:

```
        call get_mode
        jnz mode64
```

Comment: Does this answer the question of the OP? Form what the OP says about checking the size of a pointer, I guess the OP is not interested in the current operation mode of the CPU, but the basic abilities of the CPU?

Comment: It's legal to put a REX prefix on a `jcc`, so you can do better than that: [x86-32 / x86-64 polyglot machine-code fragment that detects 64bit mode at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38063529).  See also my code-golf [Determine your language's version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139717) which is a callable function that returns 16, 32, or 64 for the current mode.

Comment: @Michael, you're right that this may not answer the question, which OP hasn't clarified, despite all the comments. But I felt this *might* answer his question and I thought it would be interesting to anyone who hasn't seen it. (Of course I could have guessed that Peter had already written it.)